# Do I use "I" or "We" when I am in a group of otherwise unconnected people?

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns

Is it correct to say "**I** landed at the airport," instead of "**We** landed at the airport"?

There are many people on a plane, and unless you're a pilot and the only one on a plane, then isn't it more appropriate to say "we landed"?

Comment: Both are correct. If the context only requires talking about you, because the rest of the passengers and crew are not relevant, then "I landed" is perfectly reasonable. Using "We landed" implies a close relationship between everyone who is included in "we", which is generally just not present in a planeful of people.

Comment: **We** usually implies a relationship, but not when it comes to planes landing.  It's quite common to use "we", as in  "*We* had to make an emergency landing at such-and-such airport because one of the passengers needed medical attention."

Comment: @AndrewLeach says "I" is preferable but Tᴚoɯɐuo says "we" is more common.  I would agree that "we" is usually said. I'm curious, does anyone know if this is perhaps a regional thing.

Answer (score 1):

Both *I* and *we* are correct,

In context, it is probably irrelevant what happen to the other passengers and it is possible that the *we* meaning all the passengers could become confused with a different *we* group. eg:

> We didn't get to meet at the airport because we landed later than scheduled.